# Relationship of the do-operator in do calculus and the notion of the collapse of wave a function

Tags: quantum-mechanics, resource-recommendations, quantum-interpretations, wavefunction-collapse

I stumbled over the "do calculus" in causal modeling https://arxiv.org/abs/1210.4852
and the do-operator which is defined in this post https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/643333/298651 The do-operator defines the Post-Intervention distribution.

> Given $\text{do}(X_j=x)$, the key insight is to note that value of $X_j$ is no longer random and $P(X_j=x)=1$, which we can simply leave out of the product
> $$
> P(X_1, \dots, X_d|\text{do}(X_j=x)) = \prod_{i\neq j}P(X_i|\text{Pa}(X_i)),
> $$

It reminded me a lot about the collapse of the wave function (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_function_collapse ) in quantum mechanical measurements (a kind of intervention).

I did not find any literature or comment  discussing the potential similarity. Is there physics literature dealing with the do-calculus or an analogous concept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You make an interesting point, although not a popular one (at least not yet).  Far more common is to interpret the wavefunction collapse as Bayesian updating (upon learning new information). See for instance [Leifer and Spekkens](https://arxiv.org/abs/1107.5849), and arguably all of [Quantum Bayesianism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/quantum-bayesian/).  But the do-calculus is not about mere “learning” of information.  Indeed the whole point of causal modelling is that there is a crucial causal distinction between *seeing* a value and *setting* a value.   The former is not a cause, and the latter is a cause.

The original influential paper concerning the relationship of causal modeling to quantum systems (particularly entangled systems) is from [Wood and Spekkens](https://arxiv.org/abs/1208.4119).  They deviate from the essentials of the do-calculus in a few places (notably in Figure 26 of the arXiv version, where they curiously allow causal arrows to point to the settings S and T).  The whole point of the do-calculus is that the externally-controlled points of intervention are the exogenous inputs to a causal model, and certainly what one “does” in these experiments is to choose the settings from outside the system.  Choosing the basis in which one measures the system must by definition be a “cause” in such models.  But apart from this lapse, the paper is excellent.

With one notable exception, there are no categories of quantum interpretations which modify the description of the system when one “does” something -- in this context, choosing the measurement settings. Certainly there is no proposal in which choosing the settings collapses the wavefunction.  True, when one learns the output result of the measurement, this is associated with the mathematical wavefunction collapse, thus the motivation to think of collapse as Bayesian updating.  But the outcome is not the setting, and the do-calculus takes the setting to be a causal input, not an output at all.

Of course, many people have noted that when one infers the past behavior of a quantum system, analyzing it in classical terms, it seems “as if” the input choice of the setting has influenced what has already happened.  When one looks to see which slit a particle had passed through, it always is seen to only pass through one slit, “as if” the particle was responding to the future measurement basis.  When one looks to see the interference pattern after a pair of slits, the result makes it look like something has passed through both slits, again “as if” the future setting was important in determining the past behavior. Following through on your observation, you notice that this happens in the do-calculus; choosing an input correlates other events with that input.  That’s just cause and effect.  And here we have an interpretation of events (at the slits) seemingly correlated with an external input (the setting choice).  Could the setting be the cause of this behavior?  If so, it would have to look something like figure 27 in Wood and Spekkens.  The causal arrow would have to point from the future settings to the past.

As mentioned, there is a category of quantum interpretations that takes this observation seriously, attempting to develop causal models of this sort, with some backwards-pointing causal arrows.  Such modes are typically either called “retrocausal” or “future-input-dependent”.  (See this [Rev. Mod. Phys.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.04313) piece for a relatively recent review.)  In general, this would imply that “the wavefunction” was actually a large set of probability distributions, one for each possible future setting.  (As the number of particles in the system grows, the number of possible future settings grows exponentially, which would then explain why “the wavefunction” gets exponentially complicated with particle number.).  As described in [these](https://arxiv.org/abs/1403.2374) simple Ising-model-like examples, when one chooses the setting one would then be selecting which particular probability distribution would describe reality.  Once chosen, that distribution need not be exponentially complicated, allowing the reality to exist in space and time, rather than in some enormous Hilbert space.

But all of that would only work if the causal model was allowed to occasionally point backwards in time to past hidden variables, an idea that’s usually rejected out of hand.  Without such retrocausation, it’s hard to see how the do-calculus could matter.  On the other hand, if one entertained the possibility of hidden retrocausal effects, this viewpoint on causal modelling would seem to be absolutely essential to making further progress in developing any spacetime-based reformulation of quantum theory.